# Rails Nginx and Thin - why don't users get logged off when recycling?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I have a Rails app running on Ubuntu, Nginx, and Thin.

When I stop Nginx and I stop the Thin servers, to a $ cap deploy and then restart Thin and Nginx, I would expect the user to have to log back in.  But, they don't.

Is there a way to force them to log-in again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users don't have to log back in because their sessions are stored in a persistent session store (typically a database) that Rails doesn't modify between deployments. A logged-in user's browser send cookies on every HTTP request, and Rails authenticates these cookies against the session store.  To force users to log back in you have to modify this session store by either deleting records or changing the expiration time.

Assuming you are storing your sessions in a database using ActiveRecord,

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

should force expire all existing sessions by deleting all rows in the table that stores the sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I just tried this on my localhost, and it didn't work because I don't have a pg table called sessions.

Comment: How can I tell where my sessions are stored?

Comment: OK, I found sessions_store.rb  and I'm not using database.  Should I be using database?

Comment: If I stay with cookie-based session store, is there another way to force them to log back in?

Comment: I ran `rake tmp:sessions:clear`. But, after restarting, I didn't have to log on.

Comment: Were you in the right environment? e.g. `RAILS_ENV=production rake tmp:sessions:clear`